# Regex for masking starting 8 characters of string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to mask the starting exact 8 characters of a given string, which can contain any character and of any length, with below JAVA code.

```java
String maskChar = "x";
String fieldName = "j@#G}3 2jklWEFSD681@#";
fieldName = fieldName.replaceAll("(?:^.{8})", maskChar);
```

is giving  the output `xjklWEFSD681@#`, which is replaced with single 'x'.
But the EXPECTED OUTPUT should be `xxxxxxxxjklWEFSD681@#`.

This code have regex `(?:^.{8})`, which returns the complete & exact 8 starting characters as string,
so when it is masking, it is replacing the returned string with single `maskChar`. And this should also handle the case **when string length is less than 8 characters**, where it should mask all the characters of the given string.

So the question is, how can I make the regex return in characters NOT as a string? or please suggest different regex which does, as I am new to this.
Thanks.

Comment: `replaceAll("(?<=^.{0,7}).", maskChar)`?

Comment: What is the expected output from the `fieldName` you gave above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```java
fieldName = fieldName.replaceAll("(?<=^.{0,7}).", maskChar);
```

See the [Java regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBPgVJ/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?<=^.{0,7})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that is immediately preceded with zero to seven chars other than line break chars
- `.` - any single char other than line break chars.